# find and remove only if the file is present

Tags: shell, unix

I am working on a shell script to clear out files from a folder if they are older than 60 days. I am using find command to do that. I have one more requirement in that as if the file exist then the script can remove such files. If no files are there which are older than 60 days, i don't want my command to give any error messages.

`find AA* -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;`

I am using above given command. It gives the error message "No such file or directory" if there is no files are older than 60 days as well as if they are not starts with "AA". I don't want any such messages reported for my command.

Please help.

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you are missing the target, i. e. AA* files in current directory?

How about changing it to

```
find . -name 'AA*' -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;
```

or if you need to check only files or directories starting from 'AA' you could use -regex:

```
find . -regex './AA.*' -mtime +60 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: The first option fixed my issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't want any such messages reported for my command.

Redirect command's standard error to `/dev/null`

```
... 2>/dev/null
```